# I2C busy flag strange behaviour

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, stm32f10x, stm32cubemx, hal-library

I've been using STMCUBE combined with Keil for some time now. For most part I like the HAL library and the documentation for STM32f1xx drivers is quite good.

I'm doing a project where I am using STM32f103rb Nucleo card combined with an MPU6050 gyro/accelerometer. 
I use code generation tool STM32CubeMX in order to generate initiation function. However when I want to implement I2C I have a strange problem. STM32Cube generates all necessary initiation steps, handle is set up then GPIO pins set as OD, then finally the clock is enabled using the macro `__HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE()`, however when this macro is run within the `HAL_I2C_MspInit`, the I2C busy flag seems to be set, and is not cleared, hence I can't communicate with the MPU6050 device.

I noticed that if I put something (for example a measuring probe) on the SDA line while macro `__HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE()` is run, the busy flag is not set and my I2C communication works until I reset the micro controller.

Another(better than putting a physical probe?) way that seems to work is that after macro `__HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE()` is run, I use macros `__HAL_RCC_I2C1_FORCE_RESET()` and `__HAL_RCC_I2C1_RELEASE_RESET()`. This way my I2C communication works fine.

I think it's strange and I can't really explain the behaviour. But since I added the force reset and release reset macros, I haven't had any I2C problem, it works perfectly.

Let me know if I need to share some more code.

Comment: The I2C pull up resistors are alright?

Comment: Yes, Im using 2.7k pullups, works fine

Comment: What is the SDA line's state initially and after you touch it with the probe. What change occurs?

Comment: It is high initially, theres a short "spike" that makes it low when I have the probe connected during CLK_ENABLE, after that its high again

Comment: I'm thinking whether, the probe manages to simulate a stop condition, which clears the i2c busy flag. But then I wonder why is the bus busy in the first place, since nothing but the init function has been executed. And if I'm right, how come the FORCE_RESET and RELEASE_RESET macros manages to do it, and is it a stable solution?

Answer (score 6):

ST has released an errata sheet called:

[STM32F100xC, STM32F10 0xD and STM32F100xE high-density value line device limitations.](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/7f/05/b0/bc/34/2f/4c/21/CD00288116.pdf/files/CD00288116.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00288116.pdf)

The interesting point here is:

> 2.9.7 I2C analog filter may provide wrong value, locking BUSY flag and preventing master mode entry

There is a detailed 15 step workaround that worked for me, surprisingly for an STM32F446, so I2C peripherals of every STM32 CORTEX-M series might be affected.

During this operation, the lines must not be actively pulled up or down by a bus member. So if you connect two I2C interfaces of the same MCU to the bus, first set up the pins of both to Alternate Function/Open Drain, then call the routine, as a transition of logical levels is required.

Here is an example with HAL libraries I use after the first initialization and during runtime, if an error occurs. As said above, this is for STM32F4, libraries for SMT32F1 might differ a bit.

```c
struct I2C_Module
{
  I2C_HandleTypeDef   instance;
  uint16_t            sdaPin;
  GPIO_TypeDef*       sdaPort;
  uint16_t            sclPin;
  GPIO_TypeDef*       sclPort;
};

void I2C_ClearBusyFlagErratum(struct I2C_Module* i2c)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

  // 1. Clear PE bit.
  i2c->instance.Instance->CR1 &= ~(0x0001);

  //  2. Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
  GPIO_InitStructure.Mode         = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
  GPIO_InitStructure.Alternate    = I2C_PIN_MAP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.Pull         = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.Speed        = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;

  GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = i2c->sclPin;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sclPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = i2c->sdaPin;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sdaPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  // 3. Check SCL and SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.
  while (GPIO_PIN_SET != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin))
  {
    asm("nop");
  }

  while (GPIO_PIN_SET != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin))
  {
    asm("nop");
  }

  // 4. Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to GPIOx_ODR).
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  //  5. Check SDA Low level in GPIOx_IDR.
  while (GPIO_PIN_RESET != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin))
  {
    asm("nop");
  }

  // 6. Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to GPIOx_ODR).
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  //  7. Check SCL Low level in GPIOx_IDR.
  while (GPIO_PIN_RESET != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin))
  {
    asm("nop");
  }

  // 8. Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  // 9. Check SCL High level in GPIOx_IDR.
  while (GPIO_PIN_SET != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin))
  {
    asm("nop");
  }

  // 10. Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain , High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  // 11. Check SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.
  while (GPIO_PIN_SET != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin))
  {
    asm("nop");
  }

  // 12. Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as Alternate function Open-Drain.
  GPIO_InitStructure.Mode         = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
  GPIO_InitStructure.Alternate    = I2C_PIN_MAP;

  GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = i2c->sclPin;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sclPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_InitStructure.Pin          = i2c->sdaPin;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sdaPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  // 13. Set SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.
  i2c->instance.Instance->CR1 |= 0x8000;

  asm("nop");

  // 14. Clear SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.
  i2c->instance.Instance->CR1 &= ~0x8000;

  asm("nop");

  // 15. Enable the I2C peripheral by setting the PE bit in I2Cx_CR1 register
  i2c->instance.Instance->CR1 |= 0x0001;

  // Call initialization function.
  HAL_I2C_Init(&(i2c->instance));
}
```

Comment: Same issue with F427, workaround seems to work.

Comment: Since I could not reproduce the error anymore (changed company, current project uses only software I2C) I never got around to test the option to simply deactivate the analog filters by setting the ANOFF bitflag in FLTR register before activating the I2C peripheral, but at least I wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 5):

**This is less an answer and more a warning...**
I got stuck with the same problem and the code above helped (along with stretching the I2C reset and initialising the clock before the GPIO - see linked answers).

**However** I spent about half a day more on this than I needed to because of a newbie mistake:  *when you reset the STM32, in my case with an external programmer attached via SwD, you are usually **not** resetting your I2C peripheral.*

If you add the code above, or some other workaround, remember to occasionally try a power cycle or hard reset of your board so the I2C peripherals get reset too.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code posted by @Hugo-Arganda and @AxelBe. I have a STM32F051 and seem to have the same issue. The workaround seems to solve this as well!

To your code:
I don't see where you get the pin/port definition from. IMO this struct usage shouldn't work at all, since the HAL does not provide you with that information!

See my revised code below. I got rid of your struct and simply use hard coded pin/port definitions.

Hint: If you use CubeMX and label the SDA/SCL lines manually, you get those definitions automatically:

```
#define I2C1_SCL_Pin GPIO_PIN_6
#define I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port GPIOB
#define I2C1_SDA_Pin GPIO_PIN_7
#define I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port GPIOB
```

Revised code:

```
static bool wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint16_t pin, GPIO_PinState state, uint32_t timeout)
 {
    uint32_t Tickstart = HAL_GetTick();
    bool ret = true;
    /* Wait until flag is set */
    for(;(state != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(port, pin)) && (true == ret);)
    {
        /* Check for the timeout */
        if (timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)
        {
            if ((timeout == 0U) || ((HAL_GetTick() - Tickstart) > timeout))
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        asm("nop");
    }
    return ret;
}


static void I2C_ClearBusyFlagErratum(I2C_HandleTypeDef* handle, uint32_t timeout)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    // 1. Clear PE bit.
    CLEAR_BIT(handle->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_PE);

    //  2. Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_I2C_DeInit(handle);

    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = I2C1_SCL_Pin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = I2C1_SDA_Pin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    // 3. Check SCL and SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SDA_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SCL_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SCL_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SDA_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);

    // 4. Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SDA_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    // 5. Check SDA Low level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SDA_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET, timeout);

    // 6. Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SCL_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    // 7. Check SCL Low level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SCL_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET, timeout);

    // 8. Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SCL_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // 9. Check SCL High level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SCL_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);

    // 10. Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain , High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SDA_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // 11. Check SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, I2C1_SDA_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);

    // 12. Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as Alternate function Open-Drain.
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_I2C1;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = I2C1_SCL_Pin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(I2C1_SCL_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = I2C1_SDA_Pin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(I2C1_SDA_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    // 13. Set SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.
    SET_BIT(handle->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_SWRST);
    asm("nop");

    /* 14. Clear SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register. */
    CLEAR_BIT(handle->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_SWRST);
    asm("nop");

    /* 15. Enable the I2C peripheral by setting the PE bit in I2Cx_CR1 register */
    SET_BIT(handle->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_PE);
    asm("nop");

    // Call initialization function.
    HAL_I2C_Init(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on AxelBe response I created this version of the fix, without blocking operations, and adding the DeInit of the I2C instance. Hope you find this useful.

```c
typedef struct
 {
    I2C_HandleTypeDef* instance;
    uint16_t sdaPin;
    GPIO_TypeDef* sdaPort;
    uint16_t sclPin;
    GPIO_TypeDef* sclPort;
} I2C_Module_t;

static uint8_t wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint16_t pin, GPIO_PinState state, uint32_t timeout)
 {
    uint32_t Tickstart = HAL_GetTick();
    uint8_t ret = TRUE;
    /* Wait until flag is set */
    for(;(state != HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(port, pin)) && (TRUE == ret);)
    {
        /* Check for the timeout */
        if (timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)
        {
            if ((timeout == 0U) || ((HAL_GetTick() - Tickstart) > timeout))
            {
                ret = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        asm("nop");
    }
    return ret;
}

static void I2C_ClearBusyFlagErratum(I2C_Module_t* i2c, uint32_t timeout)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    I2C_HandleTypeDef* handler = NULL;

    handler = i2c->instance;

    // 1. Clear PE bit.
    CLEAR_BIT(handler->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_PE);

    //  2. Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_I2C_DeInit(handler);

    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = i2c->sclPin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sclPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = i2c->sdaPin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sdaPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    // 3. Check SCL and SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);

    // 4. Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    // 5. Check SDA Low level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET, timeout);

    // 6. Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    // 7. Check SCL Low level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET, timeout);

    // 8. Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // 9. Check SCL High level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(i2c->sclPort, i2c->sclPin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);

    // 10. Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain , High level (Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // 11. Check SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.
    wait_for_gpio_state_timeout(i2c->sdaPort, i2c->sdaPin, GPIO_PIN_SET, timeout);

    // 12. Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as Alternate function Open-Drain.
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C2;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = i2c->sclPin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sclPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = i2c->sdaPin;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(i2c->sdaPort, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    // 13. Set SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.
    SET_BIT(handler->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_SWRST);
    asm("nop");

    /* 14. Clear SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register. */
    CLEAR_BIT(handler->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_SWRST);
    asm("nop");

    /* 15. Enable the I2C peripheral by setting the PE bit in I2Cx_CR1 register */
    SET_BIT(handler->Instance->CR1, I2C_CR1_PE);
    asm("nop");

    // Call initialization function.
    HAL_I2C_Init(handler);
}
```

I execute this as soon as I get the HAL_BUSY response on the I2C HAL functions, here is an example:

```c
    /* HAL Write */
    status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(eeprom_handler.instance, (uint16_t)device_address, mem_addr_masked, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, src, bytes_to_write, 1000);
    if (HAL_OK == status)
    {
        bytes_written = bytes_to_write;
    }
    else if (HAL_BUSY == status)
    {
        I2C_ClearBusyFlagErratum(&eeprom_handler, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I2C analog filter may provide wrong value, locking BUSY flag and
preventing master mode entry**

The I2C analog filters embedded in the I2C I/Os may be tied to low level, whereas SCL and
SDA lines are kept at high level. This can occur after an MCU power-on reset, or during
ESD stress. Consequently, the I2C BUSY flag is set, and the I2C cannot enter master mode
(START condition cannot be sent). The I2C BUSY flag cannot be cleared by the SWRST
control bit, nor by a peripheral or a system reset. BUSY bit is cleared under reset, but it is
set high again as soon as the reset is released, because the analog filter output is still at low
level. This issue occurs randomly.

***Note***: Under the same conditions, the I2C analog filters may also provide a high level, whereas
SCL and SDA lines are kept to low level. This should not create issues as the filters output
will be correct after next SCL and SDA transition.

**Workaround**
The SCL and SDA analog filter output is updated after a transition occurs on the SCL and
SDA line respectively. The SCL and SDA transition can be forced by software configuring
the I2C I/Os in output mode. Then, once the analog filters are unlocked and output the SCL
and SDA lines level, the BUSY flag can be reset with a software reset, and the I2C can enter
master mode. Therefore, the following sequence must be applied:

**1.** Disable the I2C peripheral by clearing the PE bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.

**2.** Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level
(Write 1 to GPIOx_ODR).

**3.** Check SCL and SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.

**4.** Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to
GPIOx_ODR).

**5.** Check SDA Low level in GPIOx_IDR.

**6.** Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, Low level (Write 0 to
GPIOx_ODR).

**7.** Check SCL Low level in GPIOx_IDR.

**8.** Configure the SCL I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain, High level (Write 1 to
GPIOx_ODR).

**9.** Check SCL High level in GPIOx_IDR.

**10.** Configure the SDA I/O as General Purpose Output Open-Drain , High level (Write 1 to
GPIOx_ODR).

**11.** Check SDA High level in GPIOx_IDR.

**12.** Configure the SCL and SDA I/Os as Alternate function Open-Drain.

**13.** Set SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.

**14.** Clear SWRST bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.

**15.** Enable the I2C peripheral by setting the PE bit in I2Cx_CR1 register.

[**more**](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/8d/85/aa/39/f4/58/40/e8/CD00238166.pdf/files/CD00238166.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00238166.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a copy and paste from an STM32 errata document (actually not the one which applies to the STM32F103 mentioned in the question). It is the same workaround already mentioned (with another errata document linked and with some sample code) in another answer on this question from 1.5 years ago [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/281046/101852).

Comment: Yes, this is a copy and paste :) , but this is a perfect answer for this question, This was my problem today